# OpenCv technique for recognising relationship between objects

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to OpenCV but trying to solve the following problem:

Each "sprite" in the target images looks the same but the way they are arranged will differ:

[image: Problem]

For now I am trying to keep it simple and high contrast.

---

My question relates to technique:

1)should I look to use template matching and the try to extract the relationship of the objects once they have been extracted? 
2) should I build my own Haar cascade using the patterns below?

The distance between the sprites will change in my sample images but the sprite will be the same each time.

---

Thanks for the help;

Andy

Comment: Have you tried anything already? If it's so please update your question with your code, and tell us about the problems that you have with it?

Comment: I haven't tried yet as building my own cascade is going to take a while (its underway as we speak) - once I have an answer I will update and upload the cascade.xml

Answer (score 1):

There are Two simple steps to solve this without using haar cascades.

1. Binarize the image and apply findContours function on the image through which you can uniquely identify each sprite from this you could possibly find the no of sprite.
2. Now apply boundingRect function on the contour and with that find the center point of each sprite. Check if the x coordinate of each sprite is equal then they are on same line. If the y axis is equal then they are stack. If both are not equal then it is angle sprite

Comment: Anton thanks for this, can you provide a little more detail on the boundingRect use?  Sounds perfect as I wanted to measure the distance between the sprites as well

Comment: Ok awesome gimme sometime I can explain it with an example. Please let me know the language that you are using. If possible upload the image.

Comment: I'm using python - image wise I plan to use the image above but spilt into the 6 examples posted (so one example per image). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for taking such a long time.

As I mentioned earlier I didn't use boundingRect function. Rather I used another method to find the boundary of the sprite. I will explain the code below

Initially I've cropped the images as

[image: 1sprite.png] [image: 2linesprite.png] [image: 3linesprite.png] [image: 2stacksprite.png] [image: 3stacksprite.png] [image: anglesprite]

Step 1: Read the input image.

Step 2: Convert source image to Grayscale Image

Step 3: Conversion of gray image to Binary Image by thresholding.

Step 4: Applying findContour function to the binary image.

Step 5: If it has no contour, exit. If it has only one contour, print 1 square sprite and exit. If more than one sprite finding center and so on.

Step 6: Finding the center of the contour using moments and also drawing the 
contour to blue.

Step 7: Plotting the center point on the sprite and finding where the x and y coordinate are lying.

Step 8: Finally printing the template of the sprite.

```
import cv2
import os
import sys
import numpy as np

### inintialization #######

centre =[]
moments=[]
initX=0
initY=0
flagLine=0
flagStack=0

######### Reading input image#########

source = cv2.imread("C:/Prabhakar/Data/anglesprite.png")
cv2.imshow("SourceDisplay", source)
#### Creating Empty matrix ####
binaryImage = np.zeros(source.shape, np.uint8)
#### GrayScale Conversion ####
gray = cv2.cvtColor(source,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#### Binarization ###
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imshow("Binary Image", thresh)
##### Finding Contour #####
im2, contours, hierarchy =cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#print "No.of Contours:",len(contours)

###### Finding Center of the contour also drawing it ######

if(len(contours)==0):
    print "No Square found!!"
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    sys.exit(0)
elif(len(contours)==1):
    print "It is a Square!!"
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    sys.exit(0)
else:    
    for cnts in contours:
    moments = cv2.moments(cnts)
    centre.append((int(moments['m10']/moments['m00']), int(moments['m01']/moments['m00'])))
    cv2.drawContours(binaryImage, contours, -1, (255,0,0), -1)

    #print centre
    ##### Findind Sprite Template #####
    for i in range(len(centre)):

        initX=centre[0][0]
        initY=centre[0][1]
        cv2.circle(binaryImage, centre[i], 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        if(centre[i][0]>=initX-2 and centre[i][0]<=initX+2):
            flagStack = flagStack+1
        if(centre[i][1]>=initY-2 and centre[i][1]<=initY+2):
            flagLine = flagLine+1


    if(flagLine == len(contours)):
         print "It is a ",len(contours),"Square Line"

    elif(flagStack == len(contours)):
        print "It is a ",len(contours),"Square Stack"

    else:
        print "It is a ",len(contours),"Square Angle"

    cv2.imshow("Contour Image", binaryImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you have any doubts please leave it in the comment.

Comment: No problem at all for the wait. Thank you so much for the reply - I will try the code and report back.

Comment: Sure.. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply and sorry for my late answer back.  It works really well and is pretty close to what I need but sometimes it gives slightly the "wrong" answer.  How can I add a buffer between say angle and line (sometimes the picture looks more like line but is reported as angle as there are a few pixels difference on the line image).

Comment: Also, whenever I run more than 1 sprite it seems to say "Square Angle" even when the sprites are perfectly in line?